# SonarQube plugin in Eclipse doesn't show up in preferences

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube in eclipse and restarted eclipse, but it doesn't show up in the preferences. I'm at a loss of what to try next.

[image: I have it installed]
[image: Doesn't show up in preferences]
[image: even when I search for it]

Comment: Does it show up in `Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details`? There might be an error in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this resource out, I had never looked at the "installation details" region of eclipse before - it does appear in the installation details, and yet I do not see any errors in the .log file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have an earlier version of the sonar eclipse plugin installed? It might be neccessary to remove some files manually and the start eclipse with the -clean flag.

Find out more details in this discussion:
http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Eclipse-No-Sonar-Menus-although-installed-td5017264.html

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me, but I solved it. I've done:

1. Install from "Help -> Install new software...", but this error appears
2. Then I uninstalled it and tried to install again, but this time through "Help -> Eclipse Marketplace"
3. Then Window Preferences -> SonarQube!!

Answer (score -1):

SonarQube doesn't appear in SonarLint, I mean, in STS/Eclipse window --> preferences. . . ! even searching by it at Eclipse market place doesn't show up!